# Jomsocial content/article pages

Tags: joomla

I want to create About us, Privacy policy and terms of service page using the joomla's abck-end and i created articles for the same and crate new menu items in the jomsocial menu toolbar for the same. The menu items appears fine in the front end. Everything fine till now.

The problem is when i click on the menu item for article/content page, it moves out of com_community folder and moves to com_content page and it leaves the current design of site. My site navigation for jomsocial disappears. Content appears in default joomla's template not in jomsocial's template.

Any ideas ?? Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Do you want Jomsocial's template to be on all the Joomla pages or do you just want to be able to access the About us, etc menu links from any page on your site???

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be using the joomla template by default?  Your template nav should then have a link to go back to the jomsocial area.  Can you share the url of the site?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back double check everything.

You need to ensure you have the proper menus associated with the proper templates.

Check that joomsocail template is legitimately setup on all pages. And there is nothing over ruling or over riding it